# Can directives reference service information?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following service:

```
 myapp.service('myService', function () {

      var familyList = this;
      familyList.people = [
        { name: 'Jax', dob: '01/01/1974', cell: '3035551212', carrier: 'ATT', email: 'jax@soa.com', active: true },
        { name: 'Tara', dob: '03/01/1974', cell: '3035551313', carrier: 'SPRINT', email: 'tara@soa.com', active: false }];

 });
```

I have the following directive:

```
  myapp.directive('applyplugin', function () {
      return {
          link: function ($scope, myService) {
              $scope.myService = myService;
              alert(myService.people.length);
              $("select[id^='ms']").each(function () {
                  $(option).remove();
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

Can I reference the familyList array from the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but the service (dependencies) injection does not take place in the `link` function, but in the one definig the directive.

The code becomes:

```
myapp.directive('applyplugin', function (myService) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.myService = myService;
            alert(myService.people.length);
            $("select[id^='ms']").each(function () {
                $(option).remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You cannot inject anything in the `link` function, its signature is fixed and is `link(scope, element, attributes, ...requiredDirectives) {... }` (you won't use the last parameter most of the times, it is for when you directive requires the use of another using `^someDir` syntax)

*NOTE:* You probably want to use this `element` parameter in your link function to only affect elements that are within the directive: `element.find("select[id^='ms']").each( ... )`

Comment: thanks for this answer.  Could you take a look at my other question to see if you can answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382602/reloading-my-drop-down-when-using-a-custom-directive